# React native convert image to byteAraay and vice versa

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, base64

I have an api which gives the image in a byteAraay format and I must show the byteArray in an image. Also, I must upload the image in a byteArray format. I looked around and could not found the method for these conversion on react native though I could get the base64 format from the image on the upload. Can anyone can give me the reference for these conversions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can put `base64` data after `data:image/png;base64,` as Shown below:

```
var base64Image = 'data:image/png;base64,{PLACE_YOUR_BASE64_DATA_HERE}';
```

Comment: How can I convert the byteAraay into base64? While upload I could convert the image to base64 though.

Comment: @Kamaleshkunwar tried with, let base64String = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...new Uint8Array(array)));